# Duplicate entries in one to many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two models as seen below.

```
 public class UserModel
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Length Should not be less than 8 characters")]
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "QuestionCategory")]
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionCategoryModel> QuestionCategoryModel { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class QuestionCategoryModel
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Length Should not be less than 2 characters")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual UserModel User { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
}
```

The issue am running into is, when i try to insert data to QuestionCategory.

```
        _DbInstance.QuestionCategories.Add(category);
        _DbInstance.SaveChanges();
```

The issue is, each time am adding QuestionCategories, a new row gets added in User despite data already being there. Could someone guide me ?

### update

Category variable is coming to a call to Controller, however, am attaching the User component fetching the value from session.

```
        Category.User = (UserModel)Session["User"];
        _QCategories.SaveCategory(Mapper.Map<Degree360.ORM.Dictionary.QuestionCategoryModel>(Category));
```

Comment: Can you show your `category` variable your initializing?

Comment: @FrankerZ I have updated the code to reflect same.

Comment: Make sure the property `category.User.ID` is set to the ID of the user in the database before saving.

Comment: you can check if username exists,if exists get the User and assign it to QuestionCategoryModel.User

Comment: @RyanSearle Yes, i did. User.ID is one that already exists. however, a duplicate with a new auto generated User.ID is added after SaveChanges.

Comment: @AnuViswan Have you tried attaching the entity in your `_DbInstance.UserModel` to `category` before saving?

Comment: @RyanSearle Yes, i did. Am getting following when i tried that.
Error :Attaching an entity of type '<>' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't attach the user to the context your context here is _DbInstance you can follow this link it will provide more information
[Entity Framework Add and Attach and Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx).

I guess you have a DbSet of UserModel that i will call here ***Users*** for my example.
so the solution will be something like that.

```
_DbInstance.Users.Attach(category.User)
```

PS : you have to do it before the `SaveChanges()`

Comment: Yes, i did. Am getting following when i tried that. Error :Attaching an entity of type '<>' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values

Comment: So `category.User` is a second instance of the same user that's already attached. I think your context lives too long. The name `_DbInstance` suggests that you have one singleton context instance. If so, that's not recommended.

Comment: @GertArnold you were right. That was the issue. I was using a singleton.